# Currently text is present but it wont be autopoulated on widget, when i mouse hover on this then only it can populate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
jQuery("#edit-search-block-form--2").blur(function(){
if(jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).val()) == "")
    jQuery(this).val("Search keyword");
});

jQuery("#edit-search-block-form--2").focus(function(){
    if(jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).val()) == "Search keyword")
       jQuery(this).val("");
});
```

Comment: Hi please help me out from this issue

Comment: why are you doing it this way look at using the html5 placeholder attribute as it will do exactly as your doing in Javascript/jQuery with that code

Comment: `.blur()` and `.focus()` have nothing to do with the mouse, as such. They trigger when an element is focussed and unfocussed. Please write more about your problem, and show us the HTML this jQuery code interacts with.

Comment: you can use `.mouseover()` and `.mouseout()`

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
jQuery("#edit-search-block-form--2").val("Search keyword");
```

before this code.

You are populating it only on blur event, and to make a blur event happen, you have to first focus the element. Above code will initialize it with the value.

On the other side, you can also use the placeholder attribute to take care of all this. (From the comments)